# vim compatibility with windows 10

Tags: vim, compatibility

I have just started to get to know about vim text editor. 
I have yet been able to download vim because maybe there was a connection problem with my ISP blocking certain pages/connections.

Anyways, on the page at [softtonic](http://gvim.en.softonic.com/), it states that it is incompatible with Windows 10. But the available download on that website is the 7.3 version, while the version on the official page is 74(presumably 7.4?).

Before I start my frustrating journey of going through vim's steep learning curve, I want to at least know if the latest version can run on my system.

P.S: While at that, I would like to know if there is an alternative website to download the latest version. Just in case my problem of downloading it from the official website persists...

Comment: That softonic site doesn't look very trustworthy. It also claims gVim is not compatible with Windows 7, which I find surprising because I'm using gvim on Windows 7 right now.

Comment: @melpomene Yeah, it is also another reason why I would have hoped to have a different website to download vim from. I don't usually trust an installer from third parties..

Comment: Download it from the official site: http://www.vim.org/  It seems unlikely that it won't work on Windows 10.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge The only quality of the binary on the official site is that it was compiled by Bram himself.  There have been ~900 patches since 7.4, most of them bug fixes.  Using a more recent build is strongly recommended.

Comment: gvim is compatible with Win10. I use it all the time. Note, there is even an [updated gvim 7.4.1024](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/gvim74-1024.exe) available for Windows and hopefully we'll have regular windows builds as well.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks for the feedback and info!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the latest stable release  on [vim.org's download page](http://www.vim.org/download.php).

However, the official release is usually a bit minimal and patches are released every couple of days so you might be interested in a more complete and up-to-date build. You can find one at [the tuxproject site](https://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/).

Also, avoid sites like softonic like the plague they are.

Comment: One question left though, it is compatible with Windows 10 right? Please add it to your answer, I'll gladly accept your answer and start leaning Vim right away if it is compatible. :)

Comment: I have no idea if it's compatible or not. Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: It works on Winodws 10. Though, I didn't check detailed. In my observation, usually Vim has no problem with windows, except some configuration changes.

Answer (score 2):

I've been running gvim 7.4 (from the vim.org site) on Windows 10 for about 2 weeks with only one issue I've seen so far.  The context (right click) menu in the windows explorer no longer has an "Edit with Vim", or other vim entries.  It does allow you to select vim with the general edit menu entry.

I'm running this on a Dell XPS 8970 that was upgraded from an almost virgin Windows 7 install.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 I changed from notepad as the default text editor to Notepad ++ as the default by going into the choose default app from the Windows 7 Classic Menu options: **Default App** which brings up Control panel -> (switch View to large icons) All Control Panels Items: then select Default Apps, at this point the tool bar should read: Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Default Programs.

click: **Associate File Type or Protocol with a Program**,

Be aware the option above will not appear unless you get **All Control Panel Items** to appear. Otherwise these two options appear separately and separately you are limited to local Microsoft apps or MS Store apps.

scroll down to the extension you want to reassign like .txt, highlight the extension and click the **Change Program** button on the right above the extension list, then a dialogue box appears click **More Apps** (highlighted in blue) and then scroll to the bottom of the new dialogue box and click **Look for another app on this PC**

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, as there is not mention of the vim text editor, or softtonic for that matter.

Comment: Looks like you accidentally created second account to edit your own answer. Now accounts are merged, but your changes have been lost. Edit your answer again, you will succeed. You can found your changes here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12853219

Answer (score 0):

Had an issue with gvim.exe installer running on a Windows 10 machine.  Not entirely sure that it's compatible least as of right now.

Answer (score 0):

Installed gvim 7.1024 on Windows 10, it works OK but I can't find a way to have .txt files be opened by vim as a default.

The Windows 10 settings : default apps page to define default app to open .txt files does not show gvim as a possible app (only notepad wordpad and others)

But gvim appears in the settings system : apps and features page where can can uninstall programs.

There must be some action at install time to let windows 10 know that gvim can handle .txt file

Answer (score 0):

vim can be installed on Windows 10 and will work.

However, if you want **to get vim in context menu**, you need to **start the install.exe with administrator privileges**.
Reason: installer tries to write some files into C:\WINDOWS directory, but this is now protected from changes.

You need also admin privs, if you like to change vim files below this directory.